# c++ map element insertion

Tags: c++, dictionary, insertion

I want to insert a pointer to object into a map. Is this the right way?

```
object myobject[10];
....
mymap.insert( std::pair<int,object*>(pktctr, &myobject[pktctr]));
```

Comment: yes, it is the right way if you would like to test what your platform does in a case of an undefined behaviour

Comment: @BЈовић: Where's the undefined behaviour? It looks fine to me, as long as `pktctr` is in range and the pointer is removed before `myobject` is destroyed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MikeSeymour That is lots of assumptions :) I assumed the myobject is on stack in a method, and that it goes out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right way?

Yes, although it might read better if you used `make_pair`:

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(pktctr, &myobject[pktctr]));
```

or C++11 syntax:

```
mymap.insert({pktctr, &myobject[pktctr]});
```

The only danger is that you must make sure that the pointer is removed, or the map destroyed, before `myobject` is destroyed (or, at the very least, make sure that the pointer is never used after that). Otherwise, you'll have a *dangling pointer* and a whole world of bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: Is the fine if I clear the map in the destructor before myobject is destroyed?

Comment: @AvbAvb: Yes: the only danger is if you use a pointer *after* the objects are destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

This will work and be correct (i.e. not resulting in undefined behavior) as long as one of the following hold:

- `mymap` and `myobject` have the same lifetime (they were declared in the same scope) : you will be sure then that the map outlast the array
- the pointer is removed before the end of `myobject` lifetime (you would have and dangling pointer then, a pointer to something that does not exist anymore)

Be sure that `pktctr` never get past the end of the array.

Finally, this syntax would also work :

```
mymap[pktctr] = &myobject[pktctr];
```

EDIT:

> Actually, I am clearing the map in the destructor before myobject is destroyed.

Then you shouldn't have any dangling pointer problem AFAIK.